# Setup CI build configuration for dot net core 3.1 failed while using self contained framework

Tags: azure, build, continuous-integration, devops

How can we setup build configuration in pipeline for dot net core 3.1? Unable to setup for 3.1 from deployment center of azure portal using self contained framework `--self contained true -r linux-x64`  we are getting the below error Error:

`The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1.`

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

And with dependency trimming

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```